# converting a c++ formula into javascript

Tags: javascript

Whilst studying recursion, I attempted to get a C++ example function working in javascript.

The original function (from Stanford CS106B) is here:

```
int Raise (int base, int exp)
{
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;

    else
    {
        int half = Raise(base, exp/2);  
        if (exp % 2 === 0)
            return half * half;
        else
            return base * half * half;
    }
}

Raise(3,5);
```

My version below recurses far too many times.
What fundamental thing have I messed up?
I bet it's the line with
    var half...
I've never tried to assign a function to a variable, so that's also new territory...

```
function Raise (base, expo)
{
    if (expo === 0)
        return 1;

    else
    {
        var half = Raise(base, (expo/2));  

        if (expo % 2 === 0)
            return half * half;
        else
            return base * half * half;
    }
}

Raise(3,5);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript does not have integer division, so this line:

```
var half = Raise(base, (expo/2));
```

does not do the same thing in JavaScript as the corresponding line in C++. (If, for instance, `expo === 5`, it would recurse with a value of `2.5` for the second argument instead of the intended 2.) You can have the same effect as integer division by 2 if you use the `>>` operator:

```
var half = Raise(base, expo >> 1);
```

P.S. I should mention that in the general case, you can do integer division using [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (or [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) if the numerator and denominator have opposite signs). The bit-level operators also convert their arguments to integers if necessary, so you can use `((a/b)|0)` to get the integer part of the quotient `a / b`. You then don't have to worry about signs.

P.P.S. It would probably be a tiny bit faster to use

```
if ((expo & 1) === 0)
```

rather than

```
if (expo % 2 === 0)
```

to test whether `expo` is even. (A similar thing goes for the C++ code.)

Comment: +1, beat me to it. I was off writing a rant on `Raise` needing to be underCased, and JS's `number` type vs `int`, `double` and `float`

Comment: ah - embarrassing - I should have known javascript didn't have integer division after all my other exercises. Thanks!

Comment: Just in case OP/someone else is not attached to  division by 2: remember that `Math.floor()` rounds towards negative infinity, which may be an unexpected result. E.g.: `Math.floor(5/2)` evals to `2` while `Math.floor(-5/2)` evals to `-3`! In case you were after "more conventional" rounding towards zero, you can use either `~~(5/2)` or `(5/2) >> 0`; both look cool :)

Comment: @o.v. - That was what my P.S. was about, but I expanded it to include your point. If the numerator and denominator of the division have opposite sign, the quotient will be negative and `Math.ceil` will then truncate (round toward +Infinity, which will also be toward 0 as desired). The bit tricks (`~~`, `>> 0`, `|0`, etc.) can also be very confusing to someone casually reading the code.